# Symfony 2 - Updating a table based on newly inserted record in another table

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to create a small forum application using Symfony 2 and Doctrine 2. My ForumTopic entity has a last_post field (oneToOne mapping). Now when I persist my new post with

```
$em->persist($post);
```

I want to update my ForumTopic entity so its last_post field would reference this new post. I have just realised that it cannot be done with a Doctrine postPersist Listener, so I decided to use a small hack, and tried:

```
$em->persist($post);
$em->flush();
$topic->setLastPost($post);
$em->persist($post);
$em->flush();
```

but it doesn't seem to update my topics table.

I also took a look at http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations hoping it will solve the problem by adding cascade: [ 'persist' ] to my Topic.orm.yml file, but it didn't help, either.

Could anyone point me to a solution or an example class?

My ForumTopic is:

```
FrontBundle\Entity\ForumTopic:
        type: entity
        table: forum_topics
        id:
                id:
                        type: integer
                        generator:
                                strategy: AUTO
        fields:
                title:
                        type: string(100)
                        nullable: false
                slug:
                        type: string(100)
                        nullable: false
                created_at:
                        type: datetime
                        nullable: false
                updated_at:
                        type: datetime
                        nullable: true
                update_reason:
                        type: text
                        nullable: true
        oneToMany:
                posts:
                        targetEntity: ForumPost
                        mappedBy: topic
        manyToOne:
                created_by:
                        targetEntity: User
                        inversedBy: articles
                        nullable: false
                updated_by:
                        targetEntity: User
                        nullable: true
                        default: null
                topic_group:
                        targetEntity: ForumTopicGroup
                        inversedBy: topics
                        nullable: false
        oneToOne:
                last_post:
                        targetEntity: ForumPost
                        nullable: true
                        default: null
                        cascade: [ persist ]
        uniqueConstraint:
                uniqueSlugByGroup:
                        columns: [ topic_group, slug ]
```

And my ForumPost is:

```
FrontBundle\Entity\ForumPost:
        type: entity
        table: forum_posts
        id:
                id:
                        type: integer
                        generator:
                                strategy: AUTO
        fields:
                created_at:
                        type: datetime
                        nullable: false
                updated_at:
                        type: datetime
                        nullable: true
                update_reason:
                        type: string
                        nullable: true
                text:
                        type: text
                        nullable: false
        manyToOne:
                created_by:
                        targetEntity: User
                        inversedBy: forum_posts
                        nullable: false
                updated_by:
                        targetEntity: User
                        nullable: true
                        default: null
               topic:
                        targetEntity: ForumTopic
                        inversedBy: posts
```

Comment: Funny thing is: after I've converted my mapping information to annotations, it works like charm...

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you're making this more difficult for yourself, because you think that you have to flush your post before you can set it to an association on your topic.

Doctrine is smart enough that if you persist an entity and set it to an association without first calling flush, it'll make sure that when you do call flush, it persists that entity first, so that it has an ID which can be used with the association.

What this means is that all you really need to do is this:

```
// Assume that topic has been fetched from the DB, and post is completely new
$topic = $em->find('TopicModel', $topicId);
$post = new ForumPost();
// Fill in the post info
// Set up the association
$topic->setLastPost($post);
// And finally, persist and flush - no more effort needed
$em->persist($post);
$em->flush();
```

A nice side effect of this is that you can simply use a prePersist event listener to update the thread's last post - Doctrine will take care of everything else for you.

Alternately, if you want an approach that can be a bit easier to follow logically, you can have your Post model call setLastPost on the topic yourself - for instance, if you set the post's topic in your constructor or in a setTopic() method, add the setLastPost call in there.

It's relatively common practice to have one side of an association take care of both sides like this, to help keep things nicely synchronised - see [Working with Associations](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.1/reference/working-with-associations.html#association-management-methods).

Comment: I've tried the latter approach, but Doctrine doesn't seem to do an UPDATE on the forum_topics table. I've even tried to call $em->persist($topic), but it's the same, no effects.

Comment: Hmm, interesting - there are three situations that I know of that could cause that:

1. The topic entity isn't being managed by the EntityManager, so it can't detect changes (if you fetched the topic from the DB, it's very unlikely to be this)
2. The association isn't being mapped correctly (only changes to the owning side of an association are persisted)
3. The topic entity is configured with explicit or notify change tracking

Could you update your question with the mappings of the two models to help diagnose?